# mysql query to bring multiple count values from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

I've been trying to get multiple count values from 3 tables in mysql DB:

profile               user                               prof_opt              option
 
+-------------+ +------------------------+ +-------------------+ +---------------------------+
 
| id  | name |  | id | name | id_prof  |  | id_prof | id_opt |  | id    | parent | name   |
+-------------+ |-------------------------+ +-------------------+ +---------------------------+
| 1 | dev      |  | 1 | user1 |    1        |  |      1     | 100     |  | 100 |   null   | m1        |
| 2 | admin  |  | 2 | user2 |    3        |  |      1     | 101     |  | 101 |   100   | m1_a    |
| 3 | basic   |  | 3 | user3 |    3        |  |      1     | 102     |  | 102 |   100   | m1_b    |
+-------------+ +------------------------+ |      1     | 200     |  | 200 |   null   | m2        |
                                                         |      1     | 201     |  | 201 |   200   | m2_a   |
                                                         |      1     | 202     |  | 202 |   200   | m2_a   |
                                                         |      1     | 300     |  | 300 |   null   | m3        |
                                                         |      1     | 301     |  | 301 |   300   | m3_a   |
                                                         |      3     | 300     |  | 302 |   300   | m2_b   |
                                                         |      3     | 301     |  +---------------------------+
                                                         |      3     | 302     |
                                                         +-------------------+

Table option has data to build dynamically the user menu with options and sub options, I didn't include column url which holds file name like:

- maintainers.php
   -users.php
   -profiles.php

the idea is to get:

list of profiles, users per profile, and amount of options per profile

this query gets profile and amount of users:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, count(u.id_prof) AS nr_users
FROM profile p LEFT JOIN user u ON p.id = u.id_prof
GROUP BY p.id
```

this other query gets
profile and amount of options each profile has....

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, count(po.id_prof) AS nr_users
FROM profile p LEFT JOIN prof_opt po ON p.id = po.id_prof
GROUP BY p.id
```

but how do I mix the two results into one query??

I tried this, but doesn't work on the amount of options each profile has:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, count(u.id_prof) AS nr_users, count(po.id_prof) AS nr_options
FROM profile p 
LEFT JOIN user u ON p.id = u.id_prof
LEFT JOIN prof_opt po ON u.id = po.id_prof
GROUP BY p.id, u.id_prof
```

I'm trying to get:

| id | name  | nr_users | nr_options |
| 1  | dev     | 1              | 8               |
| 2  | admin | 0              | 0               |
| 3  | basic  | 2              | 3               |

Please could anyone post the query that would get the expected results, or point out what is missing or wrong with my query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use dependent subqueries to get your counts:

```
SELECT 
p.id,
p.name,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user WHERE id_prof = p.id) as nr_users,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM prof_opt WHERE id_prof = p.id) as nr_options
FROM profile p
GROUP p.id
```

In my experience, dependent subqueries have tolerably good performance, and are often faster than performing multiple queries.  I have no analytical proof to verify my statement about their performance, but I think they work pretty well.

Comment: @1rx please consider marking this answer as correct if you're happy with the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  p.id, 
  p.name,
  u.u_count,
  o.opt_count
FROM  profile
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id_prof,
     COUNT(id) u_count
  FROM user
  GROUP BY id_prof
) u
ON p.id = u.prof_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id_prof,
     COUNT(id) opt_count
  FROM prof_opt
  GROUP BY id_prof
) o
ON p.id = o.prof_id
```

Comment: My understanding is that this kind of query should be generally avoided, since you're performing a full scan on prof_opt and user for each row of the query.

Comment: Hello, I tried your answer, it worked as expected, but when count = 0 it shows null, no problem at all anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, count(u.id_prof) AS 
nr_users, count(po.id_prof) AS nr_options
FROM profile p ,prof_opt po , user u    where p.id = u.id_prof and u.id = po.id_prof
GROUP BY p.id, u.id_prof
```